# WebRTC to Gstreamer Bridge

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, sdp, kurento

I'm trying to stream audio from a browser to a gstreamer pipeline on a server.

I'm currently using Kurento, and modifying the Hello World example to try to  connect an RTP Endpoint to the pipeline -- but am having trouble.

I know the media is getting there because when I swap in a Recording Endpoint, I get a valid recording.

The Kurento Node JS is:

```
pipeline.create("RtpEndpoint", {}, function(error, rtpEndpoint) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Recorder problem");
            return sendError(res, 500, error);
        }

        console.log("Creating WebRtcEndpoint");
        pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint', function(error, webRtcEndpoint) {
            if (error) {
                return sendError(res, 500, error);
            }

            console.log("Processing sdpOffer at server and generating sdpAnswer");
            webRtcEndpoint.processOffer(sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer) {
                if (error) {
                    webRtcEndpoint.release();
                    return sendError(res, 500, error);
                }

                console.log("Connecting loopback");
                webRtcEndpoint.connect(webRtcEndpoint, function(error) {
                    if(error){
                        webRtcEndpoint.release();
                        return sendError(res, 500, error);
                    }
                    console.log("Sending sdpAnswer to client");
                    console.log(sdpAnswer);

                    webRtcEndpoint.connect(rtpEndpoint, function(error) {
                        if(error) {
                            webRtcEndpoint.release();
                            return sendError(res, 500, error);
                        }
                        rtpEndpoint.generateOffer(function(error, offer) {
                            fs.writeFile('/tmp/test.sdp',offer);
                            console.log("RTP OFFER GENERATED.");
                        });
                    });

                    res.type('application/sdp');
                    res.send(sdpAnswer);
                });     
            });
        });
    });
```

and my GStreamer pipeline is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvvv filesrc location=/tmp/test.sdp ! sdpdemux ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

which returns

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: timeout = 10000000000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2: timeout = 10000000000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:send_rtcp_src: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad4: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession1.GstPad:send_rtcp_src: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_1: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstUDPSink:udpsink1.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtcp
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:send_rtcp_src_1.GstProxyPad:proxypad7: caps = application/x-rtcp
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstsdpdemux.c(1213): gst_sdp_demux_handle_message (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSDPDemux:sdpdemux0:
Could not receive any UDP packets for 10.0000 seconds, maybe your firewall is blocking it.
Execution ended after 0:00:10.062018001
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

It doesnt work on FFPMEG, VLC, etc -- results are similar to "Attempt 5.3" here: https://altanaitelecom.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/continue-streaming-broadcasting-live-video-call-to-non-webrtc-supported-browsers-and-media-players/

I don't think theres a firewall issue as the pipeline and kurento instance are on the same virtual machine (which has no firewall) -- and the recording endpoint works.  Is it being linked badly?  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RtpEndpoint is tricky because you need to complete de SDP negotiation. This means that somewhere after the

```
rtpEndpoint.generateOffer(...
```

you should be invoking

```
rtpEndpoint.processAnswer(sdpAnswer, ...)
```

The tricky part is that you need to obtain the sdpAnswer from your gstreamer pipeline and this is not trivial if you want to it just using gst-launch. Probably your best option is to write a small programm creating the pipeline and generating the sdpAnswer so that you can give it back to the rtpEndpoint through your signaling mechanism.